# How to setup print excel files in jasper reports

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

i have problem with my excel when i print preview the files after i export the report into excel. How to setup the files when i print the files, it will automatic fix the size according the A4 paper?.

Answer (score 1):

```
  HSSFPrintSetup printSetup = sheet.getPrintSetup();
    sheet.getPrintSetup().setFitWidth((short) 1);
    sheet.getPrintSetup().setFitHeight((short) 0);
    sheet.setAutobreaks(true);
    printSetup.setLandscape(true);

    HSSFFooter footer = sheet.getFooter();
    footer.setCenter("Page " + HSSFFooter.page() + " of "+ HSSFFooter.numPages());
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well: Exporting to Excel and opening a Print preview did not show `A4` but `Letter`, despite the report page format being configured as A4 (that is 842 * 595 pixels).

During Excel export, Jasper calculates and sets the paper size in the `private final short getSuitablePaperSize()` method of `net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRXlsExporter` (as of JasperReports 6.2.0).

The calculation did not work correctly because the `JRParameter.IS_IGNORE_PAGINATION` flag was turned on. With this flag, Jasper considers the entire report as one single page, so page size and page width are not anymore the same as defined in the report's page format.

Leaving `JRParameter.IS_IGNORE_PAGINATION` at `false` produced the correct print preview (in A4).