# Jasperreports's Jasperviewer print incorrect size

Tags: java, printing, jasper-reports

I designed a report using iReport and i'm filling it in my Java application.
Then I'm showing result using `JasperViewer`.
The shown report is correct; but when I use JasperViewer's print button to print it; While the paper size is A5 and report size is A5 too it print the report in a A4 page! (it puts the entire A5 report in bottom left of and A4 page!)
my report's config is this:

```
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="pe_report" language="groovy" pageWidth="421" pageHeight="595" columnWidth="381" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="9fdf75fc-52e2-4af7-893b-e11093715503">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.5"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
```

And i'm showing it with this:

```
JasperReport jasperReport = null;
JasperPrint jasperPrint = null;
JasperDesign jasperDesign = null;
Map parameters = new HashMap();
jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load("/home/user1/reports/pe_report.jrxml");
jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);
jasperPrint  = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(data));
JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint,false);
```

What is the problem?

---

**Edit**
Images from output & print:
**This is what JasperView shows:**
[image]
**And This is what it prints:**

[image]

Comment: Did you read this: [how to Change Page Format in Runtime?(jasperreport)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10772240/876298) & [How to setup print excel files in jasper reports](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10814292/876298)?

Comment: @AlexK: yes; I checked that; my problem isn't setting page size; I can set it (JasperViewer & PDF export are OK; just print is incorrect!); Please check my Edit (images)

Comment: did you find a solution for this? I have a similar problem. I set the report in A4 and the preview shows fine. yet using the print button it prints a very small report.

Comment: did you find the solution???